# can I easily recomplie PHP with all my current settings and enable SOAP with the new configuration?

Tags: php, soap, recompile

I have PHP 5.1.6 running with a ton of mods and extensions enabled, is there a way to reconfigure the current settings as well as add SOAP to the mix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah; if you do `php -i|grep 'Configure Command'`, that will show you the current build options for your recompile.  Just add the option for SOAP to that.

Comment: BTW meant to ask, can I YUM this?

Comment: I don't know that much about `yum`, so maybe there's a connection I'm unaware of, but I don't see any way it relates to recompiling your PHP install.

Comment: I guess what I mean by that is: uh, `yum` it how?

Comment: yum install php-soap I think I can

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source-code of that version of PHP *(pretty old, but you surely can find it somewhere ; for instance : http://www.php.net/releases/#5.1.6 )*, yes, you can :

- use `phpinfo()` or `php -i` : in the output, there will be the "`configure`" line that was used to build your current version of PHP
- go to the sources directory, and run that configure line, with all its options ; don't forget to add the `--enable-soap` *(If I remember correctly)*, to add the new extension !
- Then build as you'd always do (`make`, `make install`)

And voila ;-)

And when you have the new PHP executable and/or module, just keep using the same `php.ini`, so you don't have to reconfigure everything.

Comment: Thanks, this will work as well but I found that I could do a YUM install php-soap and restart Apache instead

Answer (score 2):

for CentsOS 5 (Linux) I just found that I could use **yum install php-soap** and then restart Apache

Answer (score 2):

> php -i|grep 'Configure Command'

does not seem to work anymore. You can do

> php-config

Answer (score 1):

depending on your Linus distro you might be lucky and find you can simply install php-soap through your package manager

**yum install php-soap** for CentOS, or **apt-get install php-soap** for Debian/Ubuntu etc